# Bootstrap Columns not Being Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling with my columns.  They're not being responsive.  When I shrink my page down to emulate a phone query, my columns are still being spread out like the page is extra large.  I'll show a picture.

My HTML for the footer (where the issue resides):

```
<footer class="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                  <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
                  <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfService">Terms Of Service</a>
                  <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}AcceptableUsePolicy">Acceptable Use Policy</a>
                  <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}WarrentyAndReturnsPolicy">Warranty &amp; Returns Policy</a>
                  <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}ThridPartyCopyrightNotices">Third Party Copyright Notices</a>
                  <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfServicePhone">Terms Of Service For Phone</a>
                 <br><br><br>
                <p>&copy; 2016 Truespeed Internet Services - All Rights Reserved</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

My CSS:

```
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #277FD8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1100px;
}
.footer a{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.footer p{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
```

The picture:

[image]

Comment: Why are you specifying the width of the footer? Container class should be fine for that.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot.  Thanks so much for the timely response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you have the footer set to the static width of `1100px`.

If you set your footer to `width: 100%`, the columns will then be responsive.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot.  Thanks so much for the timely response!

Answer (score 1):

You can put a container for it so that I will be manageable. So it will follow your `.container`'s width.

```html
<footer class="footer">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
 <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfService">Terms Of Service</a>
 <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}AcceptableUsePolicy">Acceptable Use Policy</a>
 <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}WarrentyAndReturnsPolicy">Warranty &amp; Returns Policy</a>
 <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}ThridPartyCopyrightNotices">Third Party Copyright Notices</a>
 <a class="col-xs-2 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfServicePhone">Terms Of Service For Phone</a>
   </div>
 </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 1100px width in the footer.

Change your footer class to the following :

```
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #277FD8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```