# Footer Isn't Full Width of Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

EDIT #4: All of my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
        <title>{{var pageTitle}}</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{var protoHost}}FavIconstackoverflow32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{var protoHost}}favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{var protoHost}}css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{var protoHost}}css/print.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{var protoHost}}css/navbar-custom.css">
        {{var extraHeaders}}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="topheader col-xs-0 col-md-0">
                  <div class="phonecolours">
                    <p class="headerspacer inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:613-865-7733" class="phonecolours"> (613) 865-7733</a></p>
                    <p class="headercontact inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:613-817-7733" class="phonecolours"> (613) 817-7733</a></p>
                    <p class="headercontact inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:613-454-7733" class="phonecolours"> (613) 454-7733</a></p>
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btnstackoverflow buttonspacer">Referral Services</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btnstackoverflow buttonlinkspacer">My Account</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btnstackoverflow buttonlinkspacer">Reseller Services</button>
            </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 branding">
                  <a class="imgCon" href="{{var protoHost}}">
                      <img class="img-responsive" alt="stackoverflowinternet Internet Services" src="{{var protoHost}}img/TrueInternet.png">
                  </a>
              </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-0">
                      <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer brandingspacer buttonheader" href="https://www.facebook.com/stackoverflowInternetService"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" style="color:#3B5998"></i></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-0">
                      <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer buttonheader" href="https://twitter.com/stackoverflowinternetcanada"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style="color:#1da1f2"></i></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-0">
                      <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer buttonheader" href="https://www.instagram.com/stackoverflowinternetinternet/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" style="color:#623628"></i></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-0">
                      <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer buttonheader" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_EH7RNVnL7IUch12iHzFAQ"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-2x" style="color:#E62B24"></i></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-0">
                      <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer buttonheader" href="https://plus.google.com/116264661972220598755"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x" style="color:#DB4437"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
                    <div class="col-xs-0 container-fluid" data-expand="false">
                      <div class="row">
                      <p class="inlineParagraph navbartext"><a href="/internet" color="white"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download navIcon fa-lg"></i>View Our Internet Packages!</a></p>
                      <p class="inlineParagraph navbarspacer"><a href="/phone"><i class="fa fa-phone navIcon fa-lg"></i>Phone Services!</a></p>
                      <p class="inlineParagraph navbarspacer"><a href="/Televison"><i class="fa fa-television navIcon fa-lg"></i>Television Programs!</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="col-xs-0">
                {{var content}}
            </div>
            <div class="footerspacer"></div>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                      <footer class="footer">
                      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
                      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfService">Terms Of Service</a>
                      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}AcceptableUsePolicy">Acceptable Use Policy</a>
                      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}WarrentyAndReturnsPolicy">Warranty &amp; Returns Policy</a>
                      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}ThridPartyCopyrightNotices">Third Party Copyright Notices</a>
                      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfServicePhone">Terms Of Service For Phone</a>
                     <br><br><br>
                    <p>&copy; 2016 stackoverflow Internet Services - All Rights Reserved</p>
                    </footer>
                  </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{var protoHost}}js/showhide.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{{var protoHost}}js/navCode.js"></script>
        {{var extraScripts}}
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT #3: My original issue has been solved, but now may footer isn't responsive anymore.  See my old question to see the issue: [Bootstrap Columns not Being Responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489166/bootstrap-columns-not-being-responsive)

My footer isn't the full width of my page.  I've set the page to 100px and everything else is fitting in it perfect.  I've tried to set my width to auto (too short), too 100% (too long), and to inherit (it fits it, but I lose all responsiveness).

My CSS:

```
.page{
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.footer{
  background-color: #277FD8;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <footer class="footer">
      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfService">Terms Of Service</a>
      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}AcceptableUsePolicy">Acceptable Use Policy</a>
      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}WarrentyAndReturnsPolicy">Warranty &amp; Returns Policy</a>
      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}ThridPartyCopyrightNotices">Third Party Copyright Notices</a>
      <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfServicePhone">Terms Of Service For Phone</a>
     <br><br><br>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

The page CSS rule is a wrapper.

And the picture:

[image]

Edit: Thanks for all the replies!  I've tried nesting the Footer tag within my container-fluid and row, and it's not working.  Here's what I mean when I use 100% on my footer for width (sorry, it's not to tall, I don't know what I was thinking/typing):

[image]

Edit #2:

Navbar HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="col-xs-0 container-fluid" data-expand="false">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="inlineParagraph navbartext"><a href="/internet" color="white"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download navIcon fa-lg"></i>View Our Internet Packages!</a></p>
      <p class="inlineParagraph navbarspacer"><a href="/phone"><i class="fa fa-phone navIcon fa-lg"></i>Phone Services!</a></p>
      <p class="inlineParagraph navbarspacer"><a href="/Televison"><i class="fa fa-television navIcon fa-lg"></i>Television Programs!</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Navbar CSS:

```
.navbar{
    height: 100px;
}
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #277FD8;
  border-color: #277FD8;
  z-index: 9999px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with too tall when it's widht: 100%? To have full width of the parent element (can be your body), all you have to set is width:100% and max-width: 100%

Comment: .page {position:relative}, footer  {width:100%}

Comment: Dis you try to include `footer` in the `container-fluid` ?

Comment: why you have a wrapper of the same width as `container` of bootstrap?

Comment: @dippas I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @jelleB I've edited to show what 100% does.

Comment: @GL.awog I tried that, and it does make fit the width, the footer moves up over some content.

Comment: You might be able to solve this by specifying the CSS rule ````box-sizing: border-box;```` for the ````<footer>```` element. That way the element will include padding in the total width, which should make ````width: 100%```` act as expected. (Might or might not be necessary for child elements as well.)

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Yes, I did.  And still the same issue.  I've updated my HTML in my edit.

Comment: @Thomas Hutton it overlaps content because of position:absolute and no height specified to the footer. Since your .page have padding-bottom:50px  , give to footer height:50px;

Comment: Why do you have col-xs-0 in your navbar?

Comment: @GL.awog That worked, however, now my footer has lost its responsiveness.  It goes back to the issue I had here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489166/bootstrap-columns-not-being-responsive

Comment: @RobbinvanderJagt Thanks for noticing that, the old web designer did his own HTML/CSS/JavaScript to make a mobile navbar instead of incorporating Bootstrap's.

Comment: Remove that and just add .hidden-xs if you don't want it to be shown on mobile

Comment: Could you show the html of the entire page? I bet you've got your footer at the wrong place. It's probably surrounded by a wrong parent element

Comment: so i assume you want a sticky to bottom footer that has the same responsiveness as the upper part? that's why you don't delete position:absolute?

Comment: @jelleB At the top of my post is all the HTML.

Comment: @GL.awog I want the footer to hit Bootstrap's breakpoints and the text to respond accordingly.  But with my new HTML/CSS it's treating my footer like I've defined it to be 1100px wide.  So when I go to do mobile emulation on Firefox, it keeps the footer 1100px wide the whole time.

Comment: You are using Bootstrap incorrectly. pleasy provide a fiddle where I can work around in

Comment: Like other said, you should cleanup your markup. Moreover, don't use width: 100%, this is uselass AND risky. https://codepen.io/EmmanuelB/pen/ryhaC

Comment: Remove the CSS rule defining your page to be 1100px wide. You can't have elements with hard and large widths like that and expect the page to be responsive.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue is that the footer is wrapped in a div that has a fixed width.

```
.page {
   width: 1100px; <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM.  REMOVE THIS.
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
}
```

If you remove this, the footer will expand the full width of the window, however I don't know how removing that will affect the rest of the page.  Your best bet is to remove it, and then use bootstrap's `container` class as the page wrapper.  `Container-fluid` will span 100% width, however `container` is probably what you're looking for as it will use widths that are appropriate for each media size breakpoint (without you having to worry about defining them). If you have your page content in a wrapper with a fixed width, as you do now, your page will not be responsive because you are preventing the elements within that wrapper from scaling down any smaller than 1100px.  Just by looking quickly at your full page markup, it seems like you'd be OK if you removed the `.page` elements and changed `container-fluid` to `container`.  Keep in mind that if these sections have background colors that you want to span 100%, they will no longer be 100% once wrapped in a container.  So you'd have to do something like this:

```
#background-color {
    background: #ccc;
}

<div id="background-color">
    <div class="container">
        *content here *
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, if you want to have your footer take up 100% of the page, but the content inside the footer to only fill the container (or wrapper) width, you will want to set it up similar to this:

```
<footer>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <a href="XYZ"></a>
          etc..
       </div>
   </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: this is the way to go. and for your fixed `width` change it to `max-width`. Take notice that the `.container` class, already creates a *less-than-full-screen-horizontal-display*, so you might skip using the `width` at all.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting it up like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <footer>
    ...
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

That way your footer shouldn't interfere with the width.
(You can also try the following)

```
body,html{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Edit: Your new problem

```
.page{
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

The width here makes your 100% on the footer be treated as 1100px
Putting a fixed width on your page element also defeats the whole purpose of bootstrap. Remove that and let me know if things still go wrong.

Comment: Have you also tried setting the body,html width / height? That could be prevent your error. If not, please a bit more of your code so I can see what you've done with the header

Comment: I have tried that.  Let me update my post width the navbar HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Your footer will inherit whatever surrounds it, you need to take the entire footer html out of its container and add it at the end just befor the body tag. From there make sure it has a 100% width.

```css
footer {width:100%;}
```

```html
    <footer>
    ...
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should re-order you footer, according to [bootlint](http://www.bootlint.com/) it is only allowed to place row's in .container and .col, .col can only be placed inside .row. See footer code below

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfService">Terms Of Service</a>
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}AcceptableUsePolicy">Acceptable Use Policy</a>
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}WarrentyAndReturnsPolicy">Warranty &amp; Returns Policy</a>
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}ThridPartyCopyrightNotices">Third Party Copyright Notices</a>
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfServicePhone">Terms Of Service For Phone</a>
            <p class="col-xs-12">&copy; 2016 stackoverflow Internet Services - All Rights Reserved</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    Footer Content Goes Here.
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Though you have mentioned `width: 100%;` for `class footer`, but you placed Footer inside `class page`, whose width is `1100px`. That's why you Footer's 100% is 1100px. So, you try to place your Footer outside class page. This will help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**.container-fluid** class provides a **full width container**, spanning the entire **width of the viewport**

**Containers are not nestable** (you cannot put a container inside another container).

**footer** class with margin and padding adjustment

```
<footer class="footer">
  <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
  <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfService">Terms Of Service</a>
  <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}AcceptableUsePolicy">Acceptable Use Policy</a>
  <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}WarrentyAndReturnsPolicy">Warranty &amp; Returns Policy</a>
  <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}ThridPartyCopyrightNotices">Third Party Copyright Notices</a>
  <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfServicePhone">Terms Of Service For Phone</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

By what I understand, you just want the footer bar to be full width, but the content to be the width of the page. Here is what I came up with:

https://run.plnkr.co/najlsKreCkKZCESQ/

https://plnkr.co/edit/lS7NiTBfMSe8l4KBLxvH?p=preview

Basically, I moved the footer out of the page wrapper, and did some small modifications to it, that work:

```
<div class="footerspacer"></div>
<div class="row">
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="page">
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}PrivacyPolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfService">Terms Of Service</a>
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}AcceptableUsePolicy">Acceptable Use Policy</a>
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}WarrentyAndReturnsPolicy">Warranty &amp; Returns Policy</a>
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}ThridPartyCopyrightNotices">Third Party Copyright Notices</a>
            <a class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" href="{{var protoHost}}TermsOfServicePhone">Terms Of Service For Phone</a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>&copy; 2016 stackoverflow Internet Services - All Rights Reserved</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

By moving the footer out of the page wrapper, it takes full width, then the content inside just has to be wrapped in a div with the page class. If this isn't 100% what you wanted, let me know. I know, it isn't pretty, but it works. :)